# Product multiple columns by a single column in a dataframe

Tags: r

My datas as follows:

```
datas6=structure(list(Exp = c("BA", "CI", "CE", "DE"), Var1 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), Var2 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Var3 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L
), Var4 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Freq = c("6", "2", "7", "5")), .Names = c("Exp", 
"Var1", "Var2", "Var3", "Var4", "Freq"), row.names = c(NA, 4L
), class = "data.frame")
```

That's a basic question and I'm sorry for that, can't find a way to multiply from datas6[2] to datas6[5] by datas6[6] such this pseudo code :

```
datas6[2:5]=as.numeric(datas6[2:5])*as.numeric(datas6[6])
```

returns error :

```
Error: object (list) can not be converted automatically into a type 'double'
```

Tried this also :

```
 new_df <- ddply(datas6, (datas6[2:5]), transform, new_column = as.numeric(datas6[2:5])*as.numeric(datas6[6]))
```

do not works : `Error in UseMethod("as.quoted"`)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by

```
datas6[2:5] <- datas6[2:5] * as.numeric(datas6[,6])
datas6[2:5]
#   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
#1    0    0    0    6
#2    0    0    2    2
#3    0    7    7    7
#4    0    0    0    5
```

Comment: As simple as that ! thanks but, why we have to cast datas6[,6] and not datas6[2:5] ?

Comment: @ranell the `datas6[,6]` returns a vector while `datas6[2:5]` or `datas6[,2:5]` are both data.frame.  Here the vector gets recycled for each column.

Comment: Ok perfect, Thanks a lot !